# Want to add to a data type in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, types, functional-programming

Hi I have a data type which is

```
data MyIntStr = MyIntStr { intList :: IntList, strList :: StrInt}
type IntList = [[Int]]
type StrList = [[String]]
```

and I want to add things to the `intList` and `strList` in `MyData`. So I'm passing a default data which is just empty and then trying to add Ints to the `Intlist`:

```
putInts :: [Int] -> MyIntStr -> MyIntStr
putInts (h:t) d
    |length t /= 0 = putInts t (intList:h)
    |otherwise intList:h
```

this gives errors any ideas how to do this?

Comment: 1. `data` is a keyword. You cannot use it as a name for a variable. 2. `intList` has type `MyData -> IntList`.

Comment: @chi that is incredibly unhelpful

Comment: @NeoStreets It will be in long term.

Comment: @NeoStreets chi's pretty much on target, but have some code anyway: `putInts is d = d { intList = intList d ++ is }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to end this with some constructive aid (or so I hope) here is a version that should do what you expect:

```
type IntList = [Int]
type StrList = [String]

data MyIntStr = MyIntStr { intList :: IntList, strList :: StrList }
              deriving Show

empty :: MyIntStr
empty = MyIntStr [] []

putInts :: [Int] -> MyIntStr -> MyIntStr
putInts is (MyIntStr is' ss) = MyIntStr (is'++is) ss
```

here is an example:

```
λ> putInts [1,2,3] empty
MyIntStr {intList = [1,2,3], strList = []}
```

---

what I did:

- added `deriving Show` so I can see my example ;)
- changed `StrInt` into `StrList` because you obviously meant it
- added `empty` so I could test
- rewrote `putInts` using pattern matching and `++` to concatenate your `[Int]` lists

Comment: Thanks I get what he was saying, but I understand the basics of this it was taking the last step that was making life hard